# Overriding and New

Tags: .net

I'm not sure if this is better suited to programmers on SE.

I'm learning about inheritance, specifically how to use overrides - I can see I can either use override to extend the functionality or new to create new functionality.

EG

```
    public override int Calls(int i)
    {
        //Do some things
        return base.Calls(i);
    }
```

The above does the logic, and then calls the base class.

If I do new

```
    public new int Calls(int i)
```

Then I can implement my own logic, as if the base class never existed (as it's never called).

The thing which confuses me is I can simply remove the base class call from my override method and I *think* I get the same results as new. Meaning

```
public override int Calls(int i)
{
    //Do some things
    // return base.Calls(i); COMMENTED OUT, no base class call
}
```

The above code snippet surely is the same as `public new int Calls(int i)`

My question is, am i right - is this ultimately 2 ways of doing the same thing so it becomes better in terms of clarity for the developer (by using override or new) or are there any other differences between the 2 (any gotcha's).

Comment: Have you tried invoking your `Calls` method via a variable declared as the *base class*?

Comment: They are not the same thing. Try googling "override vs new c#".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *massive* difference between new and overrides.

In case of overrides this overwritten method is called no matter if you hold a base-class object or an object of the derived type.

with new however, the method of the derived class is called *only* if you hold an object of the derived class.
"new" is something you should be extremely careful with, and I'm just not using it.

Comment: There is no reason not to use `new`. If your child class happened to have the same method name as its parent (and they're not related), you're actually encouraged by the compiler to add the `new` keyword so the fact that they're unrelated will be explicit. I'd say you better try avoiding name collisions, not avoiding `new`.